# How to sort the date form to latest to the oldest in array of objects react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm trying to sort the date from this array of objects from the latest to the oldest. I'm trying this code, i.e. copy the array to a new `const` and then use it with `sort`, but I have the same result, no sorted date. My code is below:

```
const array=[...user?.editedBy]
console.log(array,"array")

const sortedDates = array?.sort((dateA, dateB) => dateB.date -dateA.date )
console.log(sortedDates,'sortedArray')
```

The first pic is the console log from the array and the second from `sortedDates`.

So the same result, can someone please help me figure out what I'm missing?

Thank you in advance

[image]
[image]

Comment: Those are strings not dates, wrap them with new Date() before comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in your console screenshot, those aren't actually Date objects, but strings.

So you have to map the strings to `Date` objects and compare them afterward.

```js
const sortedDates = array?
  .map(obj => { return { ...obj, date: new Date(obj.date) } })
  .sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer it does work, but I need in this array the other data as like id and the rest, this array now its returning just date. How do I fix that

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. I fixed my answer. Works now?

Comment: Also, check out the spread syntax here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer to improve the visibility.